# Electron,js serial troubles

Tags: javascript, arduino, electron, serial-port

Been trying to get Electron.js to talk to my Arduino.

```
char x = 'v';
void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
    Serial.print(x);
    delay(1600);
  }
```

I checked the IDE and it is reacting to the rendering code below:

```
var path = "/dev/ttyACM0";
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')
const {DelimiterParser} = require('@serialport/parser-delimiter')
var ports = new SerialPort({path, baudRate: 9600});
const parser = ports.pipe(new DelimiterParser({ delimiter: '\n' }))
//ports.pipe(parser);
//parser.on('ready', () => console.log('the ready byte sequence has been received'))
data=parser.on('data', console.log) // all data after READY is received
// Read the data from the serial port
//parser.on("data", (ports) => console.log(ports));

//   console.log('ports', ports);
           document.getElementById('ports').innerHTML = data;
```

The output too the application is this: SerialRead [object Object] .  It should be SerialRead v.  Below is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Read from USB port</title>
    <style>    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Read</h1>
<center>
 SerialRead <span id="ports"></span>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <div id="ports"></div>
</center>
</body>
<script src="./__renderer.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-gpu");
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: "#ccc",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true, // to allow require
            contextIsolation: false, // allow use with Electron 12+
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'tindex.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))

    // Open the DevTools.
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function() {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Electron and the Aruduino are reacting to each other, the the rendering is not working correctly.  I would appreciate any ideas.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`serialport` is a Node.js module. To be able to use a main process module in the renderer process, you need to know about the [Process Model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model).

TL;DR; use [contextIsolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) and [ipc](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to send messages between main and renderer. Keep in mind: just because you use contextIsolation, does not mean the code is safe. You need to use it properly. Don't expose powerful APIs without filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply.  I tried that route few months ago with Electron.  I am able to get IPC and serial working on Node, but serial on Electron has always been challenging.  The Nodeserial maintainer has this as an example: https://github.com/serialport/electron-serialport/commit/6cf4e28ec9df4d45e73d2ceca1e6e131af588956#diff-8a8d77cf15b2eaf50ec617c3603313fe363eaef34d8eb3c20ce12b607da55f04      Have you used Nodeserial and IPC before?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, electron.js can be problematic with native modules. I know that. Can you send your errors or a link related to the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I will look deeper into how to write the code.  Their example, though interesting, is very different than what works on a typical Node.js implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I suffered from that too. Hopefully you can find a non electronjs base solution. is the Node module using NAN? Typically converting the module to NAPI will work, but it's a painful process

Comment: Thanks!  It is painful.  Will try to answer your question later today.

Comment: and he never answered... :(

Comment: I apologize  I have been distracted by work or lack there of..  And  there are no examples I can find that show a reasonable way in communicating between Electron and a serial device.

Comment: Check Arduino IDE source code, I think v2 uses some derivation of VSCode/Theia which use electron